# Can I group attributes of one class into one map?

Tags: c++, variables, maps

If I have class "node", and wish to include all possible (say int) attributes. Is grouping them into one map good solution.
So instead:

```
    class node{
        int color;
        int isVisited;
        int weight;
    public:
    };
```

To have

```
    class node{
        map<string, int> property;
    public:
       setProperty(string property_label, int property_value) 
        {property[propery_label] = property_value;};

    };

    int main(){
        node n;
        n.setProperty("color",int(color::red));
        n.setProperty("isVisited", 1);
        n.setProperty("weight", 12);
    }
```

EDIT:
The reason to do this is that, when transforming a graph, some local properties (like is visited during some traversal, or is it marked) are needed somewhere in the middle of an algorithm, but these local properties do not represent intrinsic property of a node, and are not needed in the output. Also, sometimes I need more than one "isVisited" variables.

One more reason is to keep the class "node" universal and open for new attributes that eventually might be needed.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, may or may not be a good idea at all.

Comment: If all attributes are of the same type, it might be a good idea.

Comment: Typo for `n.colour` will be spot by compiler, whereas `n.getProperty("colour");` won't.

Comment: As others say, the answer is: `Yes, you can!` But the question is `why?` What do you want to achieve? Keep in mind that string is 'heavier' object than int, and getting properties from the map will be slower than just getting int from the class/struct.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that would be a good reason not to do it. Because of a small typo, chasing a bug through the entire code.

Answer (score 3):

The example you gave gives the impression that *any* node would have *all* the properties you provided (`colour`, `isVisited`, `weight`). If so it is (usually) better to keep the original class you started with.

There might be a few scenarios in which a map (or possibly rather `std::unordered_map`) might be superior, though; just a few examples:

- You have a large number of *possible* (but pre-defined) attributes and each node only needs a rather small subset of. Possibly an enum is better suited as key then.
- You want/need to store *arbitrary* attributes unknown at compile time.
- Each node has the same attributes, but you mainly access them via user input; then especially an `unordered_map` could be faster than a (possibly long) if-else-chain.

In the end, all depends on the use case...

For strings as keys possibly a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be an interesting alternative, too.

Answer (score 0):

A `class` (identical to a `struct` except it defaults to `private` access rather than `public`) is primarily to group elements of data and/or functionality together.

You `node` seems to simply group together three elements.  So you probably want to start off with something as simple as:

```
struct node // access is public by default
{
    int color;
    int isVisited;  // maybe a bool rather than int?
    int weight;
}
...
node myNode;
myNode.color = ...
...
std::cout << myNode.weight;
```